# Grab a String between strings using python

Tags: python

I have the following string,

```
s = {$deletedFields:name:[standardizedSkillUrn,standardizedSkill],entityUrn:urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,25),name:Political Campaigns,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Skill},{$deletedFields:[standardizedSkillUrn,standardizedSkill],entityUrn:urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,28),name:Politics,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Skill},name:
{$deletedFields:[standardizedSkillUrn,standardizedSkill],entityUrn:urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,27),name:Political Consulting,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Skill},
{$deletedFields:[standardizedSkillUrn,standardizedSkill],entityUrn:urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,26),name:Grassroots Organizing,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Skill},
{$deletedFields:[],profileId:ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,elements:[urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,25),urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,26),urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,27),urn:li:fs_skill:(ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,28)],paging:urn:li:fs_profileView:ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,skillView,paging,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.SkillView,$id:urn:li:fs_profileView:ACoAAA0C3rkBDZ7qyoWoEmj9CxUv3QW6brC836w,skillView},
{$deletedFields:[]
```

I want to grab

```
name:Political Campaigns

name:Politics

name:Political Consulting

name:Grassroots Organizing

name = [Political Campaigns , Politics, Political Consulting, Grassroots Organizing]
```

The above string is from a file i want to scrap.

Keep in mind that `name` has many instances in the file,
is there a way to grab `fs_skill` then some garbage value but then look for `name:` near it and grab that string ending at.

Comment: Hi @hacke, what have you tried so far?

Comment: re.findall(r'name:(.*?)},' , s) 
but name has many instances on my file so i was not able to get only what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [pair[5:] for pair in s.split(',') if pair[:4] == 'name' and pair[5].isalpha()]
```

Output:

```
['Political Campaigns', 'Politics', 'Political Consulting', 'Grassroots Organizing']
```

can you try above code snippet, hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain what you did ?
I need to implement the same logic on a large file which may have more occureneces of name and those garbage strings ?

Comment: split the string by ',', then compared the first four character with 'name' and also 6th char is an alphabet, if both conditions are satisfied then take the part after ':'

Comment: Can i get ur email address pramod ?

Comment: Sent you a Mail would be glad if you can help out in this Thanks.
The answer worked.